# Fix 2 divs to left edge of screen with CSS

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain why my purple box overlaps my yellow box in this demo?

I'd like my yellow box to appear first & then my purple box to be 10px below it.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/t0x0y7ax/

```css
#container {
    position: fixed; 
  top: 50%; 
  left:-55px;
}

#feedback1 {
    background:yellow;
    height: 50px; 
    width: 160px; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

#feedback2 {
    background:purple;
    height: 50px; 
    width: 160px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="feedback1">Feedback</div>

<div id="feedback2">Feedback</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Because it is rotated, if you check after you take off the rotation, it is as you expect it to be

Comment: That's an excellent point I hadn't considered. What is the best work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would just transform the container...it makes it much easier all round

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t0x0y7ax/14/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    position: fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    border:1px solid red;
    transform-origin:top left;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0%);
}

#feedback1 {
    background:yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    float: right; /* to correct order when rotated */


}
#feedback2 {
    background:purple;
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    float: right; /* to correct order when rotated */

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="feedback1">Feedback</div>
    <div id="feedback2">Feedback</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this can be done for OP's use I like this one better since it is cleaner. You could add `margin-left` to the yellow one to get the margin

Comment: Ooh. That's a very good way of doing it. And much tidier too! Many thanks!!
http://jsfiddle.net/t0x0y7ax/15/

Comment: Much cleaner...great answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the rotation as the commentator specified.  You can float them to get them to show up next to each other - http://jsfiddle.net/t0x0y7ax/2/.

```
#container {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50%; 
  left:-55px;
}

#feedback1 {
   float: left;
   background:yellow;
   height: 50px; 
   width: 160px; 
   margin-bottom:10px;
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

#feedback2 {
   float: left;
   background:purple;
   height: 50px; 
   width: 160px;
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

}

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/t0x0y7ax/12/

Comment: Thank you, Matt :) If I were to position one above the other and still fixed to the left, how do I achieve this?

Comment: You could edit the margin bottom of the yellow box to 120px, so you got 50 height + 120 margin = 170 and your width which is now the height is 160 giving you 10 margin visually

Comment: See my updated fiddle.  If you specify a height on the container and absolutely position the feedback boxes you can achieve this.  This is probably not the best approach and I would probably do this differently if I had to write it from scratch...but it does work.

Comment: That works perfectly. I'll worry about improving it for mobile/tablet devices later. Thank you, Matt :-)